# What is the $^{28}{\rm Si(}d,p)$ nuclear reaction?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, notation, isotopes

I am reading about several processes in nuclear physics that put letters in parentheses next to the names of the isotopes.

Usually two letters, separated by a comma.

Besides $d$ and $p$, I have seen a (or alpha?) and n.

I first thought d and p stood for energy (sub)levels, but now I'm thinking p is proton, n is neutron, d is 'daughter' (nuclide?) Or deuterium?  And a or 'alpha' is alpha particle....

Are these protons and neutrons and deuterons and such part of the initial reaction?  Or end result?

Answer (score 2):

That notation confused me when I first encountered it, too.  The interpretation is

$$
\rm target (incoming, outgoing) residual
$$

So your example, $\rm^{28}Si(d,p)$, suggests a silicon target exposed to a beam of deuterons (deuterium nuclei), where the particles which are detected after the interaction are protons.  The mostly likely interpretation is neutron transfer,

$$
\rm ^{28}Si + d \to p + {}^{29}Si
$$

but there are other possibilities, too.  Depending on the energies involved the $\rm^{29}Si$ nucleus might emit a gamma cascade, or re-emit the captured neutron, or fission.  But if all you have is a proton detector, then you detect $\rm^{28}Si(d,p)$, and speculating about all the different final states occupies a long section in your paper.

This notation also allows you to talk about beam reactions independently of their targets.  I did this already when I referred to your $\rm(d,p)$ as a "neutron transfer reaction."  You will also find $(n,\gamma)$ for radiative neutron capture and $\rm(n,f)$ for neutron-induced fission.