# What does the prime symbol indicate in a nuclear reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, notation

I've come across a reaction shown as $ ^7\text{Li}(\alpha,\alpha^\prime)^7\text{Li}^*$. I understand that the asterisk indicates that the final $ ^7\text{Li}$ is in an excited state, but what about the prime symbol on the $\alpha$?  Does it simply indicate the incident $\alpha$ after the interaction?  If so, would it be correct to say this reaction describes an elastic collision (inelastic scattering) with some energy imparted to the $ ^7\text{Li}$?

Comment: Hi there! Where did you see this? Can you make a link?

Comment: Hi, Deschele!  I'm afraid I cannot share this particular reference as it is currently an unpublished thesis.  My apologies.

Comment: That's no problem!

Comment: You might be interested in this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546768/what-is-the-28-rm-sid-p-nuclear-reaction?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret that as emphasis that it's an inelastic scattering reaction, so that the energy of the outgoing alphas is substantially different from the energy of the incident beam.  Of course an elastic scattering between a mass-4 alpha and a mass-7 lithium will have a pretty substantial energy change for most scattering angles, just due to kinematics; but if the lithium nucleus is knocked into some excited state, that energy has to have come from the incident alpha beam.

Note also that most $\rm^7Li^*$ decay by decomposition into $\rm\alpha+t$, rather than by photon emission.  The [ENSDF database](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) lumps all of $\rm^7Li(\alpha,\alpha)$, $\rm^7Li(\alpha,\alpha')$, $\rm^7Li(\alpha,t\alpha)$, and $\rm^7Li(\alpha,\alpha't)$ into one dataset, which only describes about five excited energy levels.  A [source which uses more than one notation](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nsr/nsrlink.jsp?1996Bu06,B) might have explanatory text about what they mean by the difference.

Comment: Thank you, rob!  I appreciate your detailed answer and the references for further information.  That answered exactly what I needed to know.